# How to mark first duplicate as unique and rest as duplicate?

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, google-sheets-formula, match, sequence

I use `IF(COUNTIF(F2:F2:F,F2:F)=1, "Unique", "Duplicate")` to mark unique and duplicate entries

but what if I want to mark the first match as unique and the rest as duplicates?

say that 10 people report the same link, but only the first person's link will be considered as unique, and the rest 9 people's link will be considered as duplicates

is that possible? the data is sorted with newest at the top, so I guess this should start searching from bottom to top to find first entries from bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(F2:F="",,IF(COUNTIFS(F2:F, F2:F, ROW(F2:F), "<="&ROW(F2:F))=1, "Unique", "Duplicate")))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF(F2:F="",,IF(COUNTIFS(F2:F, F2:F, ROW(F2:F), ">="&ROW(F2:F))=1, "Unique", "Duplicate")))
```

[image]

Comment: this is amazing, thanks! but how can it reverse the order of how it searches for duplicates? in yours, the first match from the top will be unique, but how to make the first match from the bottom unique instead?

Comment: @hofebido answer updated

Comment: @hofebido Ask more questions or follow-up questions in a separate post to make postings more focused and to assist others with a specific issue. Please do not ask further questions in the comments.

Comment: @Osm thank you for your input, really appreciate it. for the record, i did not ask something that was not already outlined in my initial message. the reason i formulated my question that way was just a polite way of reminding player0 that my initial question was not answered ("the data is sorted with newest at the top, so I guess this should start searching from bottom to top to find first entries from bottom"). makes sense? i think player0 understood this

Comment: @player0 thank you so much for solving this for me, your solution is really simple for me to understand

Comment: Hi @hofebido after seeing the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73839413/timeline#history_a13b656e-1aa8-4ca5-af1e-e0bb6feb6149) the comment is a clarification no doubt my bad, i got triggered because new user usally squize the respondant without accepting the answer or upvoting, glad to help in the future.

Comment: No problem @Osm, thank you for being so kind and taking your valuable time to assist me and make sure I understand the rules of this site, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`MATCH` or `XMATCH` only finds the first value. Use that property to compare the result with row number:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(rg,XMATCH(rg,rg)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(rg)))(A2:A16))
```

| Values | isunique? |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | TRUE |
| 2 | FALSE |
| 3 | TRUE |
| 4 | TRUE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | FALSE |
| 3 | FALSE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 1 | FALSE |

To search from bottom, set `search_method` of `XMATCH` to `-1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(rg,XMATCH(rg,rg,,-1)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(rg)))(A2:A16))
```

| Qty | isunique? Bottom first |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | FALSE |
| 2 | FALSE |
| 3 | FALSE |
| 4 | TRUE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | TRUE |
| 3 | TRUE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 1 | TRUE |

Comment: love how illustrative this is :D it works well, but same question here as below~

Comment: @hofebido `XMATCH` has a reverse search method. Set it to `-1`: `=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(rg,XMATCH(rg,rg,,-1)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(rg)))(A2:A16))`. Having said that, kindly ask new questions(even follow up questions) in a different post, so that posts maybe specific and help others with a specific issue. Avoid asking follow up questions in comments.

Comment: Noted. Thank you. I appreciate your help. Your answer is a bit too complicated for me to comprehend since I am not familiar with LAMBDA, rg, XMATCH or SEQUENCE yet, but I value your experience and will use your answer as a reference while trying to learn more advanced functions. Also, regarding the part about follow-up questions, please see my comment below. I hope it makes better sense now. Thank you again.

Comment: rg is a custom name for the Lamda function; you can use anything from x to y to z. I believe @TheMaster meant range.

Comment: @hofebido 1.Apologies for misreading the question. But you did formulate it, as if it's a new question. 2. For the record, The only thing you know in player0's answer is the function name. The way it is used is much harder(`<=&` part) to understand than straightforward functions like mine(even though the functions are newer).

Answer (score 1):

Try This =COUNTUNIQUE(C$2:C2, C2)